# Default state of Direction Flag (DF) during x86 program execution

Tags: assembly, x86, flags, cpu-registers

In disassembly, I often see that string manipulation instructions are being used without regard to the state of the direction flag (DF), like this:

```
or      ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh
xor     eax, eax
mov     edi, ebp
repne scasb
```

`CLD` or `STD` instructions are not found since function begins, neither other instructions which could affect DF flag.
So does the compiler assume the predefined state of this flag since program launch, courtesy of the loader, and being preserved unchanged while program runs?

Comment: On reset, the direction flag is cleared. It is considered polite to save `DF` before changing it, and restoring it afterwards.

Comment: The calling convention/ABI specifies the state for the `DF` and the compiler relies on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler runtime, including the code compiled for the operating system, will expect the flag to be in a certain state. Other code can use this assumption too, and doesn't have to constantly clear the flag.

[MSDN on Direction Flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7td56tzs(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

This is specified by the ABI of the platform that you're using. The [System V Intel386 ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/abi386-4.pdf) (chapter *Registers and the Stack Frame*) says that :

> The direction flag must be set to the "forward" (that is, zero)
>   direction before entry and upon exit from a function.

The same requirement is preserved in the [AMD64 ABI (Dropbox link, since x86-64.org is down)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ratxk2trzc5tc62/amd64_abi.pdf?dl=0) (section *3.2.1
Registers and the Stack Frame*) :

> The direction flag `DF` in the `%rFLAGS` register must be clear (set to
>   "forward" direction) on function entry and return.

So, yes, userland code can safely assume that `DF` is set to zero.

Comment: Quote for the i386 ABI is in page 38. This document has very useful information.