# How to let GCC know that the Direction Flag DF in the EFLAGS register has changed in inline asm?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, abi

For example, this code:

```c
void ppp(void);

void kkk()
{
    __asm__ volatile("std":::"cc");
    ppp();
}
```

Before calling *ppp()*, it needs to execute `cld` due to x86 API. Referencing [Default state of Direction Flag (DF) during x86 program execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090297/default-state-of-direction-flag-df-during-x86-program-execution).

However, the assembly comes out:

```
        .globl  kkk
        .type   kkk, @function
kkk:
#APP
# 5 "test.c" 1
        std
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
        jmp     ppp@PLT
        .size   kkk, .-kkk
```

According to GCC doc( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html ), "cc" means EFLAGS register in x86_64. Why is GCC not executing `cld`?

Comment: On x86/x86-64 `cc` as a clobber does nothing at present, and in fact it is implicit on all `asm` statements. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656857/what-happens-in-the-assembly-output-when-we-add-cc-to-clobber-list . The direction flag isn't considered a condition flag so inline assembly must clear that flag (set forward direction) if it happens to set it (backward direction). Reversing the direction flag and exiting inline assembly will cause undefined behaviour since the ABI requires it to be forward.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: You should post that as an answer, unless there's already a duplicate about `asm()` statements leaving DF changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already understand the [i386 ABI (and AMD64 System V ABI)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40348010/3857942) require the Direction Flag (DF) to be clear to enable forward direction for instructions that rely on that flag (ie. string instructions).

The FLAGS/EFLAGS/RFLAGS register on the x86/x86-64 contains many conditional flags but it also contains system flags (like the Direction Flag). Note: There are also conditional flags in the [x87 FPU status word](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fcom:fcomp:fcompp#tbl-3-21).

While inline assembly has a `cc` clobber, at present it isn't used on all target CPUs. All `asm` statements on GCC compilers that target x86/x86-64 processors have an [implied `cc` clobber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656857/what-happens-in-the-assembly-output-when-we-add-cc-to-clobber-list) and that clobber has **no effect**.

The GCC documentation is a bit vague in that what a conditional flag is for the x86/x86-64 targets. I believe the intent can be inferred from this statement in the [*6.47.2.4 Flag Output Operands*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Flag-Output-Operands) section for the x86/x86-64 targets which says:

> The flag output constraints for the x86 family are of the form
> ‘=@cccond’ where cond is one of the **standard conditions defined in the
> ISA manual for jcc or setcc**.

In particular the last sentence that references the conditional flags supported by [Jcc](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc.html) or [SETcc](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/setcc.html) gives us a clue as to what flags are assumed to not be preserved by inline assembly on x86/x86-64: Carry Flag (CF), Overflow Flag (OF), Parity Flag (PF), Sign Flag (SF), and Zero Flag (ZF).

Note: One flag in the FLAGS register that GCC doesn't care at all about is the Auxiliary Flag (AF) which can be used during the processing of certain instructions like [`AAA`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aaa).

---

To actually answer the Direction Flag (DF) question, GCC doesn't consider most of the flags in the FLAGS/EFLAGS/RFLAGS registers as conditional flags. Things like Direction Flag, Trap Flag, Interrupt Flag really don't apply. The Direction Flag is the odd man out since it is the one flag that's state is defined in the ABI. It must be cleared for forward direction.

To use the `STD` instruction or other method to set the Direction Flag (backward processing) inside an inline assembly `asm` statement without restoring it would be undefined behaviour. If you change the Direction Flag in an inline assembly `asm` statement you are responsible for restoring it in the same `asm` statement. It MUST be restored before control is returned out of inline assembly.

Comment: Using multiple separate `asm("...");` statements inside a `naked` function is possible, but it doesn't actually let you do anything you couldn't otherwise since you can't use any pure-C code either; GCC only guarantees the behaviour when the entire function body consists only of one or more `asm("...");` statements.  So really you're just writing the whole function in asm, and the calling convention is what matters, not GCC `asm` semantics.

Comment: My point was that your last paragraph made it sound like this might actually be useful as a way to get around this limitation.  But actually it's just a coding-style difference between `asm("push %rbx");` / `asm("std");` (one statement per instruction) vs. everything in one big statement like you usually need to for Extended `asm`.  I might have phrased it in a way that avoided getting people's hopes up, like "The one exception to this rule is a `naked` function, but that still doesn't help because you can't put anything *except* `asm` statements in a `naked` functions."

Comment: I know that wasn't your *intention*, that's why I'm suggesting a wording change to align the impression it gives (near the start of that paragraph) with your intentions.  Once you keep reading past the opening sentence, it becomes clearer that while technically correct, it doesn't help for getting GCC to restore DF for you.

Comment: I've decided on a wording change to eliminate any ambiguity. I have removed that last paragraph altogether. In fact it was originally an after thought and wasn't something I intended to put in there to begin with but added at the last minute. Its removal entirely deals with the issue as it wasn't germane to the question.

Comment: Yup, sounds sensible to me.  Especially since the question was how to let GCC *know* about a DF change; it still wouldn't, you could just defer clearing it manually to a later `asm` statement.